# jquery progress bar is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i was using Jquery progress bar but it is not working in it show only [object Object]% inside the progress bar i was using jquery liabry and css but it is not show properly in my page. how can fixed it i am trying add more jquery plugins.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link type="text/css" href="CSS/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ui.progressbar.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.progressbar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Button1").click(function (evt) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var data = new FormData();
                var files = $("#FileUpload1").get(0).files;
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
                        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", progress);
                    }
                }, false);
                xhr.open("POST", "Handler.ashx");
                xhr.send(data);

                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    max: 100,
                    change: function (evt, ui) {

                        $("#progresslabel").text($("#progressbar").progressbar("value") + "%").toString();
                    },
                    complete: function (evt, ui) {
                        $("#progresslabel").text("File upload successful!");
                    }
                });
                evt.preventDefault();
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .progressbar {
            width: 300px;
            height: 21px;
        }

        .progressbarlabel {
            width: 300px;
            height: 21px;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: small;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select File(s) to Upload :"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="progressbar" class="progressbar">
                <div id="progresslabel" class="progressbarlabel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi sir after your updation it is also not working kindly give me another solution

Comment: Can you verify that `var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);` is producing a valid number between 0 and 100 every time? Also, you are re-creating the progress bar every time the button is clicked, which is pointless. Move `$("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    max: 100,`...etc outside your click handler. Also move `evt.preventDefault();` to be the first line inside your click handler, otherwise you risk the page doing a full postback before the ajax call has time to return.

Comment: hi sir please provide the full code i am fresher in jquery

Comment: P.S. WDWWD's answer may not have solved everything but it is still the correct way to handle events on ASP.NET controls, if you do this in future in a more complicated page (e.g. with master pages, user controls etc) there's a good chance of duplicate IDs where .NET will rename them at runtime on the client side, so unless you handle the events with WDWWD's syntax they might not run.

Comment: If you want to check the value of `progress` you can just do `console.log(progress);` in a new line directly following `var progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);`. Then open your browser console (F12) and you can see the value. If it's not a valid number (as per this definition: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Number) or a boolean (true/false), then the progress bar will not display correctly. For the rest I haven't suggested any new code, I've just suggested moving it around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i will add following jquery reference and it is working fine.

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.progressbar.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use

```
var files = $("#<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>").get(0).files;
```

The same goes for the Button

```
$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function (evt) {
```

asp.net will rename the ID's of Controls on the client side to ensure that there are no duplicates.

Comment: also it is not working kindly do something as needful

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.progressbar.min.js"></script>

Comment: i will added following jquery reference and working fine. thanks